# What would be some good monsters to stalk the party like the Nemesis in Resident Evil?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e, story

As the question states, I’m looking for a monster that can stalk the party for the latter half of a campaign I’m running. They are only level 3-4 so it would have to be something way too strong to fight head on but preferably slow or stupid or both so they have the chance to escape it. I of course plan for them to be able to slay this monster once they gain 7-10 levels.

Comment: Generally, we accommodate this type of question. We need more details about the scenario and specifics of what encounter you want to design - these parameters are too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Revenant](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=787) would be the archetypical thing who is out to get someone, no matter what. Though Revenants are about dishing out revenge to whoever killed them, a smart BBEG might be able to trick one to track the party instead. Maybe the party carries a MacGuffin that makes the Revenant track them instead of the real murderer. The downside is, as level 6 creature, a party around levels 10-14 is going to make short work of an elite Revenant, if it doesn't pack some serious backup.

A [Golem](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=57) is another monster that mindlessly pursues whatever command it was assigned. There are at least thirteen different golems in the bestiaries. A mighty [Elite Iron Golem](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=242&Elite=true) is loaded with immunities, so one would be bad news even to a higher level party. Oh, fire heals it, it's got a poison breath weapon, reach 10', and anti-magic field too! Not to mention damage resistance 15/physical and AC 34.

A nasty surprise would be a Carrion or Flesh Golem. After getting some punishment from over-confident party, the golem reveals itself as an Iron Golem in a [Terminator 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cq36E_wTgqE) like scene. If your players are fans of 90's action movies, that would probably be an excellent clue for vacating the premises as fast as possible. Having the golem a bit broken would explain why it can be outrun - for time being. After revealing itself as Iron Golem, it would repair itself for each encounter so in the final encounter, it cannot be outrun anymore.

Comment: I like revenant more than golems because OP uses the word "stalk" whereas golems tend to be more of an 'inexorable' opponent. Moreover, they have no Survival and mediocre Perception, so it would be hard to justify them successfully hounding the party. It's a decent concept, but doesn't sound accurate to OP's intents (to me)

Comment: Well I just had the most devilish idea. We’re thinking about this in terms of “either/or”, why not both? A general working for the BBEG tried taking control of an Elite Iron Golem but is slain just as he succeeds. The party thinks they just dodged a freakin tank round when the Evil General being steeped in evil comes back as a revenant, and has just enough facilities to command the golem. I love homebrewing stuff so I’m sure I could find a way to make that plausible.